# JTextPane Syntax Highlighting Offsets Are Incorrect

Tags: java, html, jtextpane

I am creating a Text Editor with Syntax Highlighting in Java using JTextPane. When I run the program, I get this output:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkce9xvtriujizy/Output.JPG?dl=0

I want every HTML tag to be highlighted pink, but after a few tags it begins to highlight the wrong areas.

Here is the highlighting code:

```
    private void htmlHighlight() {
    String textToScan;
        textToScan = txtrEdit.getText();
        StyledDocument doc = txtrEdit.getStyledDocument(); 
        SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        while(textToScan.contains(">")) {
            StyleConstants.setForeground(sas, new Color(0xEB13B1));
            StyleConstants.setBold(sas, true);
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(textToScan.indexOf('<'), textToScan.indexOf('>'), sas, false);
            StyleConstants.setForeground(sas, Color.BLACK);
            StyleConstants.setBold(sas, false);
            textToScan = textToScan.substring(textToScan.indexOf('>') + 1, textToScan.length());
        }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of setCharacterAttributes is the length, not the end index.

This gives us:

```
    private void htmlHighlight() {
    String textToScan;
        textToScan = txtrEdit.getText();
        StyledDocument doc = txtrEdit.getStyledDocument(); 
        SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        while(textToScan.contains(">")) {
            StyleConstants.setForeground(sas, new Color(0xEB13B1));
            StyleConstants.setBold(sas, true);
            int start = textToScan.indexOf('<');
            int end = textToScan.indexOf('>')+1;
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(start, end-start, sas, false);
            textToScan = textToScan.substring(textToScan.indexOf('>') + 1, textToScan.length());
        }

}
```

UPDATE:

The substring is a problem, but without it, there is still an offset, perhaps due to the end of lines. So the only solution i have found is to recreate a new document:

```
try {
    String textToScan;
    textToScan = txtrEdit.getText();
    StyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
    SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setForeground(sas, new Color(0xEB13B1));
    StyleConstants.setBold(sas, true);
    int end = 0;
    while (true) {
        int start = textToScan.indexOf('<', end);
        if (start < 0) {
            doc.insertString(end, textToScan.substring(end), null);
            break;
        }
        doc.insertString(end, textToScan.substring(end, start), null);
        end = textToScan.indexOf('>', start+1);
        if (end < 0) {
            doc.insertString(start, textToScan.substring(start), sas);
            break;
        }
        ++end;
        doc.insertString(start, textToScan.substring(start, end), sas);
    }
    txtrEdit.setStyledDocument(doc);
} catch (BadLocationException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MyDialog.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but my new output now looks like this:

Comment: Is there any way to stop anything typed after a tag from becoming pink as well?

Comment: With a DocumentListener, you can directly control the style applied to the text.